# KivyMD MDBottomSheet not working as it should

Tags: python, kivymd

So, I'm currently new at Kivy, and I'm trying to create an app for our research using Kivy. I would like to add a Bottomsheet into our program, so I checked the KivyMD readthedocs (1.2.0.dev0 documentation) site to check on how to do it, but when I add it to our program, it doesn't work properly. In the examples from the website, it wasn't said that I have to import MDBottomSheet. So, in our code, I imported it. But, a new Unknown class emerged, and it's the MDBottomSheetDragHandle (Im adding a drag handle to the bottom sheet). May I ask, what's the correct way to create a bottomsheet if the examples given in the official site doesn't work on mine?

Tried importing MDBottomSheet